# git post-receive read oldrev newrev ref : bad variable name

Tags: bash, git, git-post-receive

```
#!/bin/bash
read oldrev newrev ref
echo "$ref"
```

return

```
remote: : not found
remote: : not found
remote: : not found
remote: : bad variable name
```

nothing work even when put "export PATH=$PATH:/bin/...etc"

Comment: it's running on a debian buster server, freshly installed

Comment: Make sure the script itself is plain-text - this is the kind of thing you get when the script is full of literal carriage returns. (The particular script you show should not behave that way but it fits the general pattern.)

Comment: This script was just for testing. My script is much bigger. After setting up several Debian servers this is the first time I have this problem. And yet, I really don't know where I could have made a error. I made this like others, even with no carriage, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

seems to do the trick.

However, it seemed to me that it was not necessary because Debian buster had utf8 as a base.
Apparently not.
Git should not take basic bash parameters